# Найти разность двух наиболее близких значений массива

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Дан одномерный массив неотрицательных целых чисел, например {1, 3, 8, 45, 21, 14}
Надо вывести значение P разности двух, наиболее близких значений.
Для данного массива P=2, т.к. 3-1=2.
Как это сделать на Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Отсортируйте массив.
2. Пробегитесь по массиву, вычисляя разности соседних элементов
3. При пробеге запоминайте текущий наименьший в рассмотренном куске и обновляйте его с приходом новой разности
4. В конце пробега выведите наименьшую разность.

Comment: не могли бы вы написать пример 2-3 пунктов?

Comment: @Hev: Ну, это ж учебное задание, вы сами должны. `for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 2; i++) { int diff = list[i + 1] - list[i]; if (bestDiff > diff) { /* что делаем тут? */ } }`

Comment: @Hev: Понятно, почему до `list.size() - 2`?

Comment: @VladD а разве не ` list.size() - 1`?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator: тьфу, и правда! Спасибо!

Comment: @Hev: Да, там `i < list.size() - 1`.

Comment: размер -1 потому что при вычитании мы делаем +1, чтобы вычесть из большего меньший

Comment: @Hev: Именно так!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, со `stream'ами`:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[]{1, 3, 8, 45, 21, 14};

Arrays
      .stream(array)
      .flatMap(element -> Arrays.stream(array).map(otherElement -> otherElement - element))
      .filter(e -> e > 0)
      .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Ps. данный код не учитывает, дубликаты в массиве.

Comment: Спасибо, но дубликаты там как раз будут